# Facebook open graph tags not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, lint

This is our page http//:www.playtown-game.com. If you view the source you will see that we define the open graph tags for facebook to show the image and description that we want. However it does not seem to work and we have tried using lint to clear facebook's cache.

Lint complains that:

```
Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a valuec     an be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

... even though we have defined those in the meta tags.. Any ideas? Thank you...

Comment: Where are your meta tags? I didn't find them in the [data scraped](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.playtown-game.com%2F) by Facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the relocate method you are using to redirect users to site http://www.playtown-game.com/playtown/app/portal/

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.playtown-game.com/playtown/app/portal/">
```

This is the markup facebook scraped https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fplaytown-game.com%2F

Your options are:

1. add the facebook open graph properties to the html file that is redirecting your users
2. or use some other redirect method for example PHP

```php
    <?php
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: http://www.playtown-game.com/playtown/app/portal/");
    ?>
```

Comment: Yeap that was it :) We added the OG tags to the script that was redirecting to the actual page. Thank you!